# Подсчитать количество не прочитанных сообщений

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста.Есть две таблицы выглядят они так

```
INSERT INTO `message_group` (`user_one`, `user_two`, `hash`, `date_group`, `del_user1`, `del_user2`) VALUES
(1, 3, 19293, '2014-04-04 12:37:34', 0, 0),
(1, 2, 30027, '2014-04-04 12:32:04', 0, 0);
```

И вторая

```
INSERT INTO `messages` (`id_ms`, `group_hash`, `from_id`, `message`, `timemsg`, `is_read`) VALUES
(1, 19293, 1, 'Привет', '2014-04-04 12:31:05', 0),
(2, 19293, 3, 'привет, как ты?', '2014-04-04 12:31:25', 0),
```

Помогите пожалуйста как подсчитать количество не прочитанных сообщений?Или  нужно в таблице messages создать еще одну строку?

Comment: select count(*) from messages where from_id=1 and is_read=0

Как то так

Comment: @naym пробовал тоже так выдает всегда 2.Даже если записей больше.
INSERT INTO `messages` (`id_ms`, `group_hash`, `from_id`, `message`, `timemsg`, `is_read`) VALUES
(1, 19293, 1, 'Привет', '2014-04-04 12:31:05', 0),
(2, 19293, 3, 'привет, как ты?', '2014-04-04 12:31:25', 0),
(3, 30027, 1, 'Привет бро, как ты?', '2014-04-04 12:32:00', 0),
(4, 30027, 1, 'что ты делаешЬ?', '2014-04-04 12:32:04', 0),
(5, 19293, 1, 'Отлично, а ты?', '2014-04-04 12:35:40', 0),
(6, 19293, 3, 'Да валяюсь, а ты?', '2014-04-04 12:37:34', 0),
(7, 19293, 3, 'ммм?', '2014-04-04 12:55:44', 0);

Comment: Кол-во непрочитанных сообщений от конкретного юзера (from_id) или просто всех не прочитанных? Если второе, то SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE is_read=0

Comment: Именно конкретного юзера нужно, а он пишет мне везде 2.

Comment: @MDJHD Все получилось, только вот у меня например id=1 показывает правильно, а захожу к id=2 показывет как у меня.
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE from_id=$user_two AND is_read=0");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev запрос правильный, возможно проблема в PHP коде. Выложите сюда код, которым вы получаете неверный по вашему результат, скорее всего вы что-то не так делаете.

Comment: @MDJHD
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE from_id=$user_one AND is_read=0");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
 <?=$row[0]?>
Вот он У меня считает на моей страницы все верно, а у другого пользователя не правильно, пробывал поставить OR from_id=$user_two Еще то вообще фигня получается

Comment: Ну из того, что вы предоставили, трудно понять. Выложите более полный код,  где вы пытаетесь получить и вывести кол-во сообщений для нескольких юзеров одновременно, скорее всего вы неправильно обрабатываете результат, возвращаемый вызовами mysql_fetch_array(), можете например, сюда - http://pastebin.com